# Function execution took 60027 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have looked at several other timeout posts but nothing seems to help. I have a very basic setup going on here using a brand new functions project. In my logs I constantly see 'timeout'

Any ideas??

Here is the code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.use(cors);

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Mateo");
});
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is how I execute my function

```
https://us-central1-anxietybox-6177e.cloudfunctions.net/app/hello
```

Heres a screenshot of logs

[image]

UPDATE

After making the changes suggested below I am still not having any luck. I'm not sure how much more bare bones it can get than this..

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Mateo");
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: What you do doing to run your function?  Could you copy the actual text of any errors or logs into your question?

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated my post.

Comment: I have to guess since I haven't used `express` in a number of years, but it looks like you're constructing your object for export _before_ composing the endpoints. Try making the call to `onRequest` last.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I appreciate the response however that did not solve the issue. Same result in the logs.

Comment: You don't need to use `bodyParser` because Cloud Functions already does that for you (and using it twice might actually break things). Just look at `req.body` for parsed JSON bodies. Also, you do `use(cors)` but `cors` is a factory function and that might also be breaking things. Strip out the middleware, see if that works, add it back one at a time to find the culprit would be my recommendation.

Comment: I narrowed it down to the cors. Once I removed it I received the response I was expecting. Whats interesting is that I use the same cors settings on another project I developed about 6 months ago. All is working well there. Thanks!